# TIOBE Index: why c++ is in 3rd place and C is having more land in the last year?

Tags: c++, c, comparison, ranking-systems

Searching for c++ ranking on the [TIOBE index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWxmU.jpg), I was stumped to see that C is in front of C++, and from 2017, C took a leap. Could someone explain why?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

TIOBE themselves comment on the [large changes in language percentages](https://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/):

> we see a lot of other huge ups and downs. This has to do with Google re-indexing, which is quite volatile.

It clearly isn't the case that the usage of C halved and then doubled again in the space of a year: the software world doesn't work like that. Therefore you have to question what TIOBE is measuring and whether it is a useful metric.

Much the same thinking applies to C Vs C++: there are, by TIOBE's metric, more web pages about C programming than C++ programming - but this doesn't necessarily tell you anything about how the languages are actually used. Given the history of C and C++, it would be surprising if the were more pages about C++ than C.